# passing data between 3 activities and getting data=null in onActivityResult() in the 1st activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have an `AppCompatActivity(MainActivity)` which has a recyclerview and on clicking the card item it is taking me to the `2nd AppCompatActivity`. I am passing the values via intent and sending `mCtx.startActivityForResult(intent,1)` from the `recyclerview_adapter.ViewHolder`.

Data passed from activity 2 to 3:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(2ndActivity.this, 3rdActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user", user);
                            intent.putExtra("location", location);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Then after clicking on **SUBMIT** button in the 2nd Activity it takes me to the 3rd Activity. Here I send data by calling

```
setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK,new Intent().putExtra("user", user).putExtra("location", location));
finish();
```

After I get Back to the 1st Activity(MainActivity) The `onActivityResult()` **Intent Data** is null.

How can I get data when I'm passing data through 3 activities?

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if you are going from 3rd activity to first, it will be null since 3rd activity will not be setting result with `setResult()` method for the first Activity.

Comment: Then How can I get it to work from 3rd activity to 1st activity?

Comment: Please post some code. If you specify Activity in startActivityForResult(),
onActivity result will expect result from that activity, not 3rd. Use other mechanism like broadcast to successfully transfer data from 3rd to 1st Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the third activity to the first you ***MUST*** set the intent extras again, that is because intent extras are not remembered when going from one activity to another, then to another one again.